# http.post(url, postData, options) does not set header

Tags: post, angular, http-headers

I have a problem when use HTTP post method in the following code:

```
    let body = JSON.stringify(applicationLink);
    let requestHeaders = new Headers();

    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.set('Content-Type',  ['application/json']);
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);

    let reqoptions =  new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });



    return this._http.post(this._applicationLinksUrl + this._linkServicePath,body,reqoptions).map(res => res.json())
```

When I execute the code I see an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http..... Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http....' is therefore not allowed access.

Request Method:OPTIONS is mde instead of post
Request URL:http://localhost:7001/workprocess-service/resources/links
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:7001
Response Headers
view source
Allow:OPTIONS,POST,GET,HEAD
Content-Type:application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Date:Thu, 26 May 2016 11:10:25 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 26 May 2016 09:02:27 CEST
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:7001
Origin:http....
Referer:http....
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
```

and my data is not linked to the request.

If I remove `reqoption`

```
return this._http.post(this._applicationLinksUrl + this._linkServicePath,body).map(res => res.json())
```

the request is a POST but  i receive an error 415 ( Unsupported Media Type)

```
Request URL:http://localhost:7001/workprocess-service/resources/links
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Remote Address:[::1]:7001
Response Headers
view source
Connection:close
Content-Length:22
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 26 May 2016 11:14:44 GMT
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:48
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:7001
Origin:http:....
Referer:http:.....
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
view source
{labelFR: "dsds", labelNL: "dsds", url: "dsds"}
labelFR
:
"dsds"
labelNL
:
"dsds"
url
:
"dsds"
```

My data is linked to the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your server set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` because you are sending a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) "Cross Origin Resource Sharing" request. Which simply means you are sending the request to a url that's not the same as the url you are sending from.

I see your backend is `servlet/3.0`, you can enable CORS "for all origins" by adding a web filter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"*"})
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I still have the same result.

I feel that the complaint did not even reach the server

Comment: @Florence The post request doesn't get sent until the preflight request "OPTIONS REQUEST" returns successfully. So, is the option request getting returned without errors ? if not, what is the error? is it still `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access...` ?

Comment: @ Abdulrahman  
the preflight request "OPTIONS REQUEST" returns successfully.
Request URL:http://workenv-test....
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.32.135.180:2005

Comment: @Florence are they the same `10.32.135.180` and `test.smals...`, if yes, then just send the request to `test.smals....` to not trigger CORS at all. If they are not the same,, I edited my answer and changed the `WebFilter` to include `urlPattern` please try it.

Comment: @Florence also, what is the current error ? is it still `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access...` ?

Comment: @ Abdulrahman, they are the same

yes the error is Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the request

Comment: The get request works because you didn't change the headers on it. right? if you change the default headers, then the `OPTIONS` request will get sent. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be sent from server not from client.  From cmd if you do `curl -i 10.32.135.180:2005`, do you get the header in the response ?

Comment: @Florence to clarify, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be present on the response headers **NOT** the request headers.

Comment: @ Abdulrahman i tried your solution
"@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"*"}) ..." and remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the request headers
It works fine. 
Thank you very very very much

Comment: @Florence You are very * 10 welcome :D, few notes since this is your first question, 1- you don't need to `@tag` my name, this is my answer and I will always get a notification. 2- I don't know how you use the servlet on the backend, but you can set the header on many other ways without a filter, 3- if you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote count.

Comment: 1 ok
2. i have use your solution , it work fine thus i don't change it :-)
3. ok i do it